# BluetoothLE Android. Непонятное отключение от Gatt

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Пытаюсь установить соединение с устройством, которое время от времени включается, передает данные и отключается. Пробовала разные варианты и вот получилось с таким Callback:

```
protected static BluetoothGattCallback callback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("BluetoothGattCallback: onConnectionStateChange: status:%d newState:%d", status, newState));
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server. Flag = " + connectionStateFlag);
            mainThreadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    gatt.getDevice().connectGatt(applicationContext, true, callback);
                }
            }, 2000);
            return;
        }

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected to GATT server. Flag = " + connectionStateFlag);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                   ...
        }

    }

};`
```

Вроде все работает, но почему-то иногда через секунд 20 после подключения к Gatt приходит снова onConnectionStateChange c cостоянием Disconect. При этом номер клиента в строчке в логе
BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=9
увеличивается. Без этого дополнительного переподключения этот номер тот же, что и при предыдущем подключении. Причем иногда это переподключение повторяется несколько раз, а иногда вообще не происходит. И еще почему-то вдруг Bluetooth перестает реагировать на включение устройства и приходится снова запускать скан, чтобы соединиться, а иногда даже перезапускать сам Bluetooth. Не пойму в чем может быть дело? 
Попробовала на другом телефоне на 4.4 иногда все совсем гладко работает никаких дополнительных переподключений. Но иногда эти переподключения происходят каждый раз. Никакой системы. Мне главное, чтобы гарантировать, что я не получаю 2 gatt для одного устройства одновременно. А судя по тому, что я иногда начинаю получать 2 onCharactericsticChange на один запрос, похоже, что именно это и происходит. Причем я не могу никакой системы найти в поведении приложения. Не зависит ни от телефона, ни от версии android. То все четко работает без проблем, то вдруг все идет вразнос, потому что на каждый запрос приходит 2 ответа и вся последовательность вопросов и ответов сбивается.

Comment: Дело вполне возможно может быть в глючной реализации Bluetooth вашего устройства. По факту практически нет ни одного телефона, который бы работал с Bluetooth так, как заявлено в Android SDK. Даже Нексусы работают иногда по-другому. Попробуйте с другими телефонами, например, чтобы подтвердить или опровергнуть мою догадку

Comment: Значит тут ничего нельзя сделать? На некоторых телефонах будет правильно работать, а на других будет глючить? Может можно как-то эту ситуацию программно исправить? Я бы не обращала внимание, но в результате этого я иногда вдруг начинаю получать вместо одного события onCharacteristicChance два. Я думаю, что получается 2 Gatt одновременно для одного устройства. Я пробовала закрывать прошлый Gatt перед новым connectGatt(), но тогда onConnectionStateChange c cостоянием Disconect начинает приходить каждые 20 секунд и телефон работает только на соединения и отключения.